# "Cannot set property of undefined error" when trying to convert the data from one format to another

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to convert data from one format to another:

The input format json is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "part_number": "12312311",
    "part_description": "HELIUM FILLING AND GAS CALIBRATION KIT",
    "quantity": "3",
    "available_quantity": "0",
    "ordered_tool_id": "28",
    "tool_id": "15",
      "wh_data": [
      {
        "wh_name": "TI02 - (DHL)",
        "wh_id": "3",
        "wh_code": "TI02",
        "wh_qty": 2
      },
      {
        "wh_name": "TI03 - (Secunderabad WH)",
        "wh_id": "4",
        "wh_code": "TI03",
        "wh_qty": 1
      }
    ],
    "tool_order_id": "22"
  },
  {
    "part_number": "90FG34",
    "part_description": "LINEARITY PHANTOM KIT",
    "quantity": "2",
    "available_quantity": "0",
    "ordered_tool_id": "29",
    "tool_id": "17",
    "wh_data": [
      {
        "wh_name": "TI02 - (DHL)",
        "wh_id": "3",
        "wh_code": "TI02",
        "wh_qty": 1
      },
      {
        "wh_name": "TI03 - (Secunderabad WH)",
        "wh_id": "4",
        "wh_code": "TI03",
        "wh_qty": 1
      },
      {
        "wh_name": "TI06 - (Bangladesh)",
        "wh_id": "7",
        "wh_code": "TI06",
        "wh_qty": 1
      }
    ],
    "tool_order_id": "22"
  }
]
```

I have to convert it into this format:

```
{
  "sso_id": "123",
  "tool_order_id": "22",
  "od_req_qty": {
    "28": "3",
    "29": "2"
  },
  "post_od_tool": {
    "28": "15",
    "29": "17"
  },
  "post_qty": {
    "3": {
      "28": "2",
      "29": "1"
    },
    "4": {
      "28": "1",
      "29": "1"
    }
  },
  "submit_fe": "1"
}
```

I had written code for the conversion as follows:

```
convertLogic(data, ssoid) {
    var toolOrderId = data[0].tool_order_id;
    console.log(toolOrderId);
    var values = '{"sso_id":"' + ssoid + '","tool_order_id":"' + toolOrderId + '","od_req_qty":{},"post_od_tool":{},"post_qty":{},"submit_fe":"1"}';
    var jsObj = JSON.parse(values);
    console.log(jsObj);
    var warehouseIds = [];


    data.forEach(element => {
      var orderToolID = element.ordered_tool_id;
      var quantity = element.quantity;
      var toolId = element.tool_id;
      jsObj.od_req_qty[orderToolID] = quantity;
      jsObj.post_od_tool[orderToolID] = toolId;
      var warehouses = element.wh_data;
      warehouses.forEach(warehouse => {
        jsObj.post_qty[warehouse.wh_id] = {};
        warehouses.forEach(warehouse => {
          jsObj.post_qty[warehouse.wh_id][orderToolID] = warehouse.wh_qty;
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

But it is giving this error :
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property '28' of undefined

Can anyone help me and tell me how to do the format conversion. I had wasted my whole day and completely exhausted but able to do the conversion.

Comment: `var values = '{"sso_id":"' + ssoid + '","tool_order_id":"' + toolOrderId + '","od_req_qty":{},"post_od_tool":{},"post_qty":{},"submit_fe":"1"}';
    ` WHY are you making a string to convert to an object, just make the object.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are using code like `object[propertyName] = someValue`, you need to make sure that the object is "defined" before. Otherwise it will consider it as `undefined` and hence the error.

Eg: for this line in your code -

```
jsObj.od_req_qty[orderToolID] = quantity;
```

You need to do something like -

```
jsObj.od_req_qty = jsObj.od_req_qty || {};
jsObj.od_req_qty[orderToolID] = quantity;
```

Similarly for others as well.

Check [the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6w2pcff/). The error disappears in the console.

Comment: "post_qty": {
    "3": {
      "28": "2",
      "29": "1"
    },
    "4": {
      "28": "1",
      "29": "1"
    }
  }

Comment: vandesh. The ouptut should be in the above format. But the currently it is showing as post_qty

3:{29: 1}
4:{29: 1}
7:{29: 1}

Comment: That could be some problem in your code, but the error in the original post is solved